# Problem with altering property's value of an object that is inside a HashSet in JAVA

Tags: java, equals, hashset

I'm studying java and facing a really weird problem, i think it's easier to explain this along with my code

So this is my class:

```
class Node
{
    private int val;

    public Node(int val)
    {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int getVal()
    {
        return this.val;
    }

    public void setVal(int newVal)
    {
        this.val = newVal;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.val;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("Inside equal of " + this.val);  
       //i expect it will print out when i use set.contains()
        if(this.hashCode() == ((Node)obj).hashCode())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is my Main block using HashSet that working with class Node

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Set<Node> s = new HashSet<>();
        Node n1 = new Node(1);
        s.add(n1);
        /*as i know, when we add a object to the set, we actually add a refference to the origin                             memory area (the one that n1 points to) to the set*/
        
        if(s.contains(n1))
        {
            System.out.println("YES");
        }
        
        for(Node i : s)
        {
            i.setVal(5);  //i expect n1 to change too and it does
        }

        for(Node i : s)
        {
            System.out.println(i.getVal());
        }
        System.out.println(n1.getVal());   //n1 changes
        
        if(s.contains(n1))
        {
            System.out.println("Still here");
            //This is where i don't understand why this does not print ?
        }
        System.out.println();
    } 
}
```

This is my cmd

```
D:\Desktop\draft\JavaDraft>java Main
YES
5
5
```

I don't understand why set does not realize n1 still be in it and why the code inside function "equals" of class Node is not triggered because as i know, HashSet uses "equals" to get uniqueness of all of it's element right? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no safe way or good time to modify objects in a set.  Don't.

Comment: Yup. The *`Hash`*`Set` is an implementation which uses an object's *current* hash to store the element (and look it up by the same value). By modifying the hash code, the set *should* somehow get notified that the hash value changed, so the set can recalculate were to store it. However, it doesn't, so there is no way for the set to know the object's hash has changed.

Answer (score 1):

> HashSet uses "equals" to get uniqueness of all of it's element right?

Nope

[HashSet](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java) is an facade for a HashMap, where the items are stored in the key set. The HashMap creates and compares the key hashCode from it's internal hash nodes.

Once the item is stored under its hashCode array element, it is there. Changing the hashCode will not replace it. What you wrote is a bad example how not-to-use the hashCode in the HashMap.

The *contains* method will check the key (hash array) of the underlying hashmap key set, not calling the equals method of all stored objects.

Comment: `equals()` will still be used to check if the objects in the set are equal/unique. The hashcode is only used to filter the list of objects to check/compare against.

Comment: But i need to make the "Node type object" unique by it's "val property" so i override the hashCode function. Is overriding the hashCode function the way to reach what i'm trying to do ?

Comment: As i understand your explanation, "set s" will check the index 5 (as i change the hashCode of n1 to 5) and the index 5 is empty so it leads to "s not contain n1 anymore" but there is still a reference to the object that n1 point to in index 1 right ?

Answer (score 0):

That is because by modifying the value of the Node, you are also changing the hashcode (thanks to your hashcode override). This is generally not the case and should not be the case as you do not want the hashcode to be variable. It should be constant and unchanging.

The underlying code of HashSet uses a HashMap, and the internal methods that `contains()` uses will use the hashcode of the object to determine a bucket to store your node in. Thus, when your hashcode is set to the value 1, and you call `add()`, the node n1 is stored for example at bucket 1. When you changed the value to 5, the hashcode is now 5 and calling `s.contains(n1)` will try to check for your node in bucket 5 which is empty (null).

A correct way to proceed will be to delete your implemented hashcode override and let the default implementation do its job. See also:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Set<Node> s = new HashSet<>();
        Node n1 = new Node(1);
        System.out.println(n1);
        s.add(n1);
        /*as i know, when we add a object to the set, we actually add a refference to the origin                             memory area (the one that n1 points to) to the set*/

        if(s.contains(n1))
        {
            System.out.println("YES");
        }

        for(Node i : s)
        {
            i.setVal(5);  //i expect n1 to change too and it does
        }

        for(Node i : s)
        {
            System.out.println(i.getVal());
        }
        System.out.println(n1.getVal());   //n1 changes

        System.out.println(n1);
        if(s.contains(n1))
        {
            System.out.println("Still here");
            //This is where i don't understand why this does not print ?
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

class Node
{
    private int val;

    public Node(int val)
    {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public int getVal()
    {
        return this.val;
    }

    public void setVal(int newVal)
    {
        this.val = newVal;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("Inside equal of " + this.val);
        //i expect it will print out when i use set.contains()
        if(this.hashCode() == ((Node)obj).hashCode())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Output:

Without Hashcode override

```
Node@4783da3f
YES
5
5
Node@4783da3f
Still here
```

With Hashcode override

```
Node@1
YES
5
5
Node@5
```

Comment: You're right about the hashCode changing, but the better solution isn't to not override hashCode, but to not mutate the object once you add it to the set.

Comment: surely there must be cases where the object needs to be mutated, and in that case even if they are to be stored in the same location you can still compare to see if it is really equals?

Comment: but yes, that does make sense to not modify the object in the set if the hashcode is dependent on the value not changing

Comment: No, there aren't any such cases when it would be a good idea.

Comment: If you need to mutate the object, you should first remove it, then mutate it, then add it back in. Anything else is asking for trouble.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the info! i ll keep that in mind. Can I assume that this will also apply to Map or only Set?

Comment: Yes, also to Map. :-)

Comment: Oh I see it now through your bucket example, but my intention is to differentiate "Node object" by it's "val property" so i override the hashCode function to make "set s" recognize that two different objects have the same "val property" are actually different. But now in both bucket 1  and bucket 9 (after i change the val of n1 to 9) there are 2 reference that both point to the object that n1 points to right ?

Comment: No. it is trying to find n1 in bucket 9, but n1 is actually in bucket 1. Meaning it thinks n1 is not in the set

Answer (score -1):

You need to understand the difference between pass-by-reference and pass-by-value. Your override of the hashcode actually takes effect. However, you did not create a new object, the object in n1 and s is actually the same one.

Comment: I dont think this is not related to pass-by-reference/pass-by-value?

Comment: Yes i aware it now, as i see, "set s" will check the index 5 (as i change the hashCode of n1 to 5) and the index 5 is empty so it leads to "s not contain n1 anymore" but there is still a reference to the object that n1 point to in index 1 right ?